# JQUERY: Create a sortable list on top of an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a word bank, in between two images. I want the user to be able to drag the word from a word bank onto the images, such that they're sortable. So I've used drag & sort.
I can do this with boxes, but when I drag the words to the image, it just hides behind the image. I'm not sure if it's placed anywhere either.

Please help!

```js
sortable5();

function sortable5() {
 $(".words1").draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  connectToSortable: ".sortConnect",
  start: function (event, ui) {
   ui.helper.css("list-style", "none");
  },
  stop: function (event, ui) {
   ui.helper.css("font-size", "10px");
   ui.helper.css("list-style", "none");
   ui.helper.css("display", "inline");
   ui.helper.css("padding", "1px")
  }
 });
 $(".words1,.sortConnect").sortable({
  connectWith: "#wordBank,.sortConnect",
  receive: function (event, ui) {
   ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
   var currentListID = this.id; //where the item is dropped
   var originatedID = ui.sender[0].id; //where item came from
   var itemContent = ui.item[0].innerHTML; //which item it is (or ui.item[0].id)
   var currentListLength = this.children.length;

   //if current item is dropped in the word bank, remove the list-inline-item

   if (!ui.helper[0].classList.contains("list-inline-item")) {
    ui.helper[0].classList.add("list-inline-item");
   }
  }
 });
 $().disableSelection();
}
```

```css
.bank 
{
 margin-top: 50%;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 position: relative;
 background: #EFD8D4;
 border-radius: 50% / 10%;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
 text-indent: .1em; 
 border: 4px solid black;
 min-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
 <div class="col-12 fillTop"></div>
 <div class="col-4 sortConnect">
  <img class="img-fluid images sortConnect" src="IMAGES/mirror.png">
 </div>
 <div class="col-2 justify-content-md-center">
  <ul class="col-2 bank" id="wordBank">
   <li class="words1">Word 1</li>
   <li class="words1">Word 2</li>
   <li class="words1">Word 3</li>
   <li class="words1">Word 4</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="col-4 sortConnect">
   <img class="img-fluid images sortConnect" src="IMAGES/mirror.png">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried z-index yet?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use 'img' tag as a container, img should have no children and be used only as an image. Use a div and add a background-image to it. You can add a diferent class to each div so you have a diferent image for all of your containers.

```js
sortable5();

function sortable5() {
    $(".words1").draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        connectToSortable: ".sortConnect",
        start: function (event, ui) {
            ui.helper.css("list-style", "none");
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.helper.css("font-size", "10px");
            ui.helper.css("list-style", "none");
            ui.helper.css("display", "inline");
            ui.helper.css("padding", "1px")
        }
    });
    $(".words1,.sortConnect").sortable({
        connectWith: "#wordBank,.sortConnect",
        receive: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
            var currentListID = this.id; //where the item is dropped
            var originatedID = ui.sender[0].id; //where item came from
            var itemContent = ui.item[0].innerHTML; //which item it is (or ui.item[0].id)
            var currentListLength = this.children.length;

            //if current item is dropped in the word bank, remove the list-inline-item

            if (!ui.helper[0].classList.contains("list-inline-item")) {
                ui.helper[0].classList.add("list-inline-item");
            }
        }
    });
    $().disableSelection();
}
```

```css
.bank {
    margin-top: 50%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background: #EFD8D4;
    border-radius: 50% / 10%;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: .1em;
    border: 4px solid black;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.img-1 {
    background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img-2 {
    background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 fillTop"></div>
    <div class="col-4 sortConnect">
        <div class="img-fluid images sortConnect img-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 justify-content-md-center">
            <ul class="col-2 bank" id="wordBank">
                <li class="words1">Word 1</li>
                <li class="words1">Word 2</li>
                <li class="words1">Word 3</li>
                <li class="words1">Word 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 sortConnect">
            <div class="img-fluid images sortConnect img-2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```